# Excel spreadsheet/workbook data connections: Two way communication with applied filter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, power-query

So let me pose you guys a scenario.

There are several users all inputting data into a single spreadsheet. This work is initially assigned to these users by a manager who, after the data is input, reviews and then edits the data, reassigning the data to someone else for a new task, which is then further input upon.

Unfortunately, sharing the spreadsheet has, in the past, led to the loss of a lot of data and with this option of the cards, this requires each individual user to constantly come in and out of the spreadsheet when .

I, in my limited Excel knowledge, was hoping to achieve a solution to this, by establishing a data connections from individual workbooks to compile a Master spreadsheet of everyone's work. I managed to figure this part out using the powerquery tool, but this fails to resolve our issue as this data cannot be further edited by the manager for reassignment.

Now what I was hoping to achieve from this, is a two-way communication between workbooks or worksheets. And, potentially, two-way communication with applied filters. So only the data assigned to the user appears in the corresponding sheet/book for the user to which it is assigned.

Is such a thing possible?